# Predicting Extent of Exothermic Reactions

Tags: enthalpy

Sodium Acetate is widely used in hot packs due to the fact that it produces an exothermic reaction when it reacts with water.

I decided to see if other sodium salts, such as sodium bromide, sodium sulphate, etc. would produce similar exothermic reactions in hopes of finding a potential substitute for sodium acetate.

Is there a reason why some of these sodium salts would react with water to produce a larger enthalpy change than others? Is this predictable given the molecules' properties and/or geometry? Can enthalpy change at all be predicted given every property we currently know about these molecules?

Comment: Difficult to predict.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the exothermic behavior of sodium acetate and water is the exothermic crystallization of a supersaturated solution of sodium acetate in water. Go look up [hot ice](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hot%20ice)